# Get the difference between two datetime objects in minutes in python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have two datetime objects created by strptime in Python:

```
date_string = "Wed, 18 Dec 2013 09:30:00 GMT"
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
```

and

```
end_date_string = "Wed, 18 Dec 2013 10:15:00 GMT"
end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date_string, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
```

Datetime objects are created successfully so i get

```
>>>date
datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 18, 9, 30)
>>>end_date
datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 18, 10, 15)
```

I want to count the minutes the two datetimes differ. I do

```
diff = end_date - date
```

and i get

```
 datetime.timedelta(0)
```

So it says that they are the same dates?No difference at all?
Also seconds property is zero

```
>>>diff.seconds
0
```

How can this be made to work?

Comment: Which version of python are you on?

Comment: Can't reproduce that. Copying and pasting your code gives `datetime.timedelta(0, 2700)`.

Comment: `(datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 18, 10, 15) - datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 18, 9, 30)).seconds` produces `2700`. Check your code again?

Comment: damn...to me too....But I copied and pasted from Idle in here, and  didn't work i Idle, then copied and pasted from here to idle and worked....what the....!!...sorry guys

Answer (score 7):

```
import datetime

date_string = "Wed, 18 Dec 2013 09:30:00 GMT"
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
end_date_string = "Wed, 18 Dec 2013 10:15:00 GMT"
end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date_string, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
print (end_date-date).total_seconds()
```

Gives

```
2700.0
```

Comment: `.total_seconds()` would be better ... It accounts for days too.

Comment: yes it does, but i am not creating the datetime object like you did, i am using strptime and it shows zero

Comment: @Apostolos - python 2.7.2 gives the correct result, even using strptime

Comment: Yes it does eventually...Maybe something i overlooked...though i did copy and pasted the code directly from idle...Anyways...thank you guys

Comment: Giving you all points just for trying to solve my problem that didn't exist...:)

Answer (score 1):

it's kinda weird, i get the correct result:

```
>>> date_string = "Wed, 18 Dec 2013 09:30:00 GMT"
>>> date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
>>> end_date_string = "Wed, 18 Dec 2013 10:15:00 GMT"
>>> end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date_string, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
>>> diff = end_date - date
>>> diff
datetime.timedelta(0, 2700)
>>> diff.seconds
2700
```

is this the whole code?

Comment: yes....I copied and pasted from idle (see comment above)...Works now...don't know what got in to it...

Comment: maybe was just a misplaced assignment of date or end_date